# How to hyperlink to an image with a dynamic URL?

Tags: html, image, dynamic, url-rewriting, url-routing

I would like to link to an image, which seems to have a dynamic (changing) and ever renewing/expiring URL.

- Would it be possible, to link to the image on the original server's location, and somehow overcome the dynamic/renewing URL (also since I would like to retain the coupling with the original server's location and the associated web document).

Any suggestions on how to go about?

Answer (score 0):

If one can find the image's `id`-attribute, one can hyperlink to `base-URL`**#id**.

It will not solely open the image in a browser's window; nevertheless, it will open the `base-URL` at the specific height of that image.